# Why am I getting this class tkinter.Entry.get() AttributeError error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-interface, tkinter

I'm sorry for my bad English.

I get an error when I try to `get()` the `Entry` named `entry` from outside the class.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'entry' ""
```

Example Code:

```
class asd:

    def gui(self, guiwindow, labelplacex, labelplacey, textx, texty, entryx, entryy):
        self.root = tk
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=aimage_path)
        self.label = tk.Label(image=self.image)
        self.label.pack()
        self.label.place(x=labelplacex , y=labelplacey)
        self.text = Label(guiawindow, text="Code:")
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.place(x = textx,y = texty)
        self.entry = Entry(guiwindow)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.place(x = entryx,y = entryy)
        self.button = Button(Tk(), text="Back Menu", command=self.asdfg)
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

asd.gui.entry.get()
```

How to do this??

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First, you need to create an instance of `asd`, and second, you need to call the `gui` method.

For example, something like this:

```
asd_instance = asd()
asd_instance.gui(...)
asd_instance.entry.get()
```

Not: `...` represents all the parameters that you need to pass to `gui`, which are irrelevant to the problem. The point being, you must first create an instance of the class before you can get an attribute of the instance. In this case the attribute you want won't exist until you call the `gui` method. Thus, you must first create an instance, then call the `gui` method, and only then can you access the attribute.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukBoran:  I left out all of the parameters to the call to `gui()` since they weren't relevant to the solution, but otherwise it should work. I'll try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try `asd.entry.get()` instead.

Assuming self.entry has already been defined, you should be able to access it by calling the class itself and then the variable, since the word 'self' means the class itself.

gui in this case is just a function and self.entry belongs to the class asd, not the function gui.

Comment: `asd` is a class; it won't have an instance of `entry`. The class needs to be instantiated first.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just assumed that he didn't post the full code since he said example code, my bad